# Having issues with Shebang in ROS cfg file

Tags: python, ros, shebang

Trying to get a shebang working and any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Code in cfg file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Error I'm getting:

```
invalid preprocessing directive #!
    2 | #!/usr/bin/env python
```

I've also tried other variations like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and got the same error.

Other relevant information:
python version is 3.8.2

python locations according to  $ type -a python

```
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /bin/python
```

Comment: when do you get that error? When running cmake?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compile a python file ... You should not do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your `cfg` file, I would say there is nothing wrong with that shebang. Of course, I assume the rest of your code checks out.

If I were you, I would double check your `CMakeLists.txt` file to make sure your `cfg` files are declared properly. Here is an example, where `cfg/sample.cfg` is a path in the repo where CMakeLists.txt is located.

```
# Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
   cfg/sample.cfg
)
```

Also, check that your `find_package(...)` directive includes `dynamic_reconfigure`.